# React Component fails to re-render after update from Redux Store

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, jsx, conditional-rendering

Can anyone help me figure out why my Component is not updating after dispatch?

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
     const { isAuthenticated } = state
     return { isAuthenticated }
}

class LoginForm extends Component {

 handleSubmit(event) { 
        event.preventDefault();
        const { dispatch } = this.props
        const credentials = this.state
        dispatch(attemptLogIn(credentials)); 
}


//    Dispatch works properly when API validates Login:
//               Redux Log:  
//                nextState:{ authReducer: {isAuthenticated: true}}

render() {
    const { isAuthenticated } = this.props;
        return (
  <div>
    { isAuthenticated && <div> Authenticated: True </div> } 
                         // Does not render even after dispatch

      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
     {... Form Stuff ...}
      </form>
    </div>
  )
}

export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps)(LoginForm))
```

Just simple conditional render from Redux store, I am expecting the extra div to show up to inform the user that he has authenticated, but It does not render.

This type of example of conditional rendering was used in the AsyncApp example during the Redux Async Tutorial, so I'm not sure why it doesn't work. My actions are dispatched, and reducers successfully update the state, passing it down to the connected component. Here are my reducers:

```
const initialState = { isAuthenticated: false}

const authReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch(action.type){
    case ('USER_AUTHENTICATED'): { 
        return Object.assign({}, state, {
            isAuthenticated: true,
            userPermissions: action.userInfo.userPermissions,
            instanceType: action.userInfo.instanceType
            }
        )
    }
    case ('INVALID_CREDENTIALS'): { 
        return Object.assign({}, state, {
            isAuthenticated:false
            }
        ) 
    }

    case ('LOG_OUT'): { 
        return initialState 
    }
    default:
            return state
    }
}

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    authReducer,
    routerReducer
})

export default rootReducer
```

Does anyone know why my Component does not re-render?

Comment: Write your function mapStateToProps form outside of your class LoginForm component.

Comment: @KuldeepSaxena This was a mistake from posting the code here - I will re-edit, my mapStateToProps actually IS outside of the component - I just pasted my example here incorrectly :\

Comment: a fiddle please

Comment: Working on it, it will take some time to load all the dependencies

Comment: Is the reducer you posted your only/root reducer? Or do you combine more?

Comment: @BalázsÉdes I have updated my example. So - I guess I am supposed to specify  further my state function deconstruction operator, thx to Kuldeep

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your mapStateToProps function to this.

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
 const { isAuthenticated } = state.authReducer;
 return { isAuthenticated };
}
```

Comment: So, I must always specify which reducer to gather state from, if there are multiple reducers?

Comment: Yes, define only those props for which you actually want to re-render your component.
For better performance always specify your props.

For eg. If you have an user object and you're only using a particular property of it in your render function then define it like that:

`username: state.user.name` instead of `username: state.user`